# What does "${PWD##*/}" mean in a Github Action for Docker?

Tags: docker, yaml, airflow

I was using this [repo](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) to run an Airflow image and noticed these lines in the Github [workflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/.github/workflows/ci.yml):

```
      - run: docker build -t "${PWD##*/}" .
      - run: docker run "${PWD##*/}" python -V
      - run: docker run "${PWD##*/}" version
```

I understand that `docker run` takes arguments of the form `[OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`, so I know that the image is being determined by `"${PWD##*/}"`, but I am not sure what this is actually doing.

I thought it might be part of the YAML spec for Github Actions but I was unable to find a match in the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet). After looking at the documentation for `docker run` I am unsure of where to look next.

What does `"${PWD##*/}"` signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not docker or github specific, but shell.

See https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

> `${string##substring}`
>
> Deletes longest match of $substring from front of $string.

So the code `"${PWD##*/}"` deletes everything until (and including) the last slash in `$PWD`, so it gets the directory name without the whole path.

Another possibility would be:

```
"$(basename $PWD)"
```

Comment: This makes sense, my understanding from your answer is that it takes the result of pwd, e.g. `/foo/bar/boo` and returns `boo`